# Unable to get data using document.getElementById() in IE7

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retreive the value from select tag for selected option in Javascript

This is working fine in Mozilla but not in IE7.
Example:

```
function uploadFiles()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('fileName').value;
    alert(x);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's a `<select>` then you should be using:

```
var s = document.getElementById('fileName');
var x = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a `value` attribute on each `<option>`: http://jsbin.com/uluki (http://jsbin.com/uluki/edit to edit):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="fileName">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>

  <a href="#" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('fileName').value); return false">Show selected value</a>
</body>
</html>
```

All I do is `alert(document.getElementById('fileName').value)`. Works in IE6, IE7, IE8, Opera 9, FF2, FF3+, Chrome 2+ (and probably every other browser). It's defacto now, again **as long as you have a `value` on each `<option>`**.

If you don't have a `value` on each option, Greg's answer is the way to go. Works everytime.